# is there a program that performs CRUD functions with phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I need to enable a client to be able to be able to create, update and delete items from a mysql database, but it'll be too confusing for him to do it via phpmyadmin. Is there a program for users to use that is a lot simpler that will do exactly the same as if he were editing via phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

A Google search turns up this: http://www.phpscaffold.com/. You paste in your table definition and it generates a script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old, there are now several tools to generate admin panels from MySQL databases.

Most require a minimum level of knowledge in PHP & MySQL.

I would recommend **PHP DRUD Generator**, which has an easy-to-use user interface, and allows you to generate a complete PHP CRUD from MySQL Database without any programming knowledge.

For coders: the CRUD is generated with a very clean and structured code, based on an MVC structure, a mini router, PHP, Bootstrap and jQuery classes.